# parsing an object with unknown key/values with retrofit and GSON

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit2

Hi I have the following data class

```
data class EntryField(
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val label: String,
    val values: HashMap<String, String>,
)
```

I expect a JSON that could be like this ( for the values part )

```
{ "values": {
      "7": "40214 - cos of rev. Coffee\/Tea",
      "14": "40215 - cos of rev. Softdrinks",
      "15": "40224 - cos. of rev. Wines",
      "6": "40225 - cos of rev. Beer",
      "10": "40226 - cos of rev. Liquor\/Spirit",
      "9": "40400 - cos of rev. Flowers",
      "13": "40403 - cos of rev. shop",
      "11": "40405 - cos of rev. Other",
      "8": "40500 - cos of rev. Excursions" }
}
```

However, The items could be more or less and have different key/value pairs. How would I parse these? Setting a hashmap like I did above doesn't work.

Comment: It actually should work. Please show retrofit initialization code.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Also, could you please also post the part of the code where you set Retrofit up?

Comment: I found the solution. The problem was that I was trying to use a hashmap. When I changed this to Map it worked!